# Writing a pandas dataframe to a csv file and renaming on a for loop

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, csv

I have a script that reads SQL db to a pandas data frame which is then concatenated together to form one dataframe on a loop. I need to write this second data frame to a csv file and rename this from a list of ID's

I am using pd.to_csv to write the file and os.rename to change the name.

```
for X, df in d.iteritems():
    newdf = pd.concat(d)
    for X in newdf:
                export_csv = newdf.to_csv (r'/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/X.csv', index = False, header = None)
                for X in NAMES:
                    os.rename ('X.csv',X)
```

This is the code that concatenates the data frames together.
In the third loop, NAMES = 'rt35' but in the future this will be a list of similar names.

I expect to get a file named rt35.csv. However I either get r.csv or X.csv and this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The files are writing correctly, the only issue is the name.

Comment: Give an example of input data and how output should looks like

Comment: I just recognized, you use X three times as a variable of nested {for} loops. Have you tried to rename these variables, so they are different (you know the alphabet has more than 20 letters, you don't have to be that stingly ;-). Then second: the loop with the call to rename seems ambiguous. Would you like to create copies of the same file with multiple names? but if NAMES is a fixed list, you know, that only the csv would survive, that was created at last. Could you maybe add some comments in your code to explain, what you intend to do?

Comment: If I understood you right NAMES contains the string 'rt35'. You should rather use ['rt35.csv'] because in expects a list and if given a string, it will treat the string as a list of characters, which then results in "r" in the first iteration. Your files are name "r" not really "r.csv", right? and then the second iterations of the rename loop yields "t", but there is no file anymore with "X.csv" which could be renamed and that's why you get the OSError. If you rather want the files to be copied, you need to call another function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the X variable is inside of a string so python considers X as a character and not as a variable. You should do it like that :

```
export_csv = newdf.to_csv (r'/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/{}.csv'.format(X), index = False, header = None)
```

Same here :

```
for X in NAMES:
    os.rename (X +'.csv',X)
```